# MATLAB: Curve fitting to scattered data in plotmatrix

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, plotmatrix

The graph below is created with `[H,AX,BigAx,P] = plotmatrix(x);` in MATLAB. Instead of scattered points in the off-diagonals, is it possible to have an approximating curve?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

reading the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plotmatrix.html), it seems that this function is only useful for scatters, which makes sense, since typically points in a matrix could be all over and fitting a curve would not make sense.  Maybe using subplot() ( [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html) ) would be more appropriate and allow more versatility?

Answer (score 0):

After creating the plots with [`plotmatrix`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plotmatrix.html) you can loop over each off-diagonal scatter plot, fetch the associated [X](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.primitive.line-properties.html#property_d119e606208) and [Y](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.primitive.line-properties.html#property_d119e606289) data, [perform the curve fitting](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data_analysis/linear-regression.html), and then [plot the results](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/line.html) as follows:

```
data = randn(50,3);  % Random sample data
[hScatter, hAxes] = plotmatrix(data);

for index = find(~eye(size(hScatter))).'  % Loop over off-diagonal plots
  X = get(hScatter(index), 'XData');      % Get X data
  Y = get(hScatter(index), 'YData');      % Get Y data
  betas = [ones(numel(X), 1) X(:)]\Y(:);  % Simple linear regression
  xLine = get(hAxes(index), 'XLim');      % Use axes limits for X data
  yLine = betas(1)+xLine.*betas(2);       % Compute regression line
  line(hAxes(index), xLine, yLine, 'Color', 'r');  % Plot red regression line
end
```

And here's the resulting plot:

[image]